# Use Alarm Manager to set Notification at specific time but my receiver class is not called on time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

```
        Long time = prefs.getLong("dailynoti", 0);  
        Intent intent = new Intent(cn, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("Desc", "Description...");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cn, 1055, intent,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) cn.getSystemService(cn.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

and my mainifest file

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.mypackage.NotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And this same code is use in same project but now in same project another module it will not work Broadcast Receiver isn't call at given time 
my notification code is in Receiver file but Receiver class isn't call.
I checked all things like time is also get properly. so what is the problem . please help...

I used many solution like

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cn, 1055, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
//FLAG_NO_CREATE
//FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

Comment: why down vote the question.? I try many things but not get solution so i post a question about it.   if I am wrong then tell that point in comment so i change it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I think that will work is instead of `alarmManager.setRepeating()` use `alarmManager.set()` and when the alarm triggers then set the next alarm. This will give you almost accurate results. Why almost? Because due to [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) introduced in Android M. So this will give you between 0 to +5 min delay.